# How do I unlock the screen?

Tags: screen, unlock

I just installed 18.04 and after a few minutes the screen locks and I have no idea how to unlock it, so I have to restart the machine. There must be a simple way, but no suggestions jump at me.

Comment: Do you mean a screen with the time showing in large numbers? If not this screen can you share a screen shot of the screen you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, the screen with the time and some arrows pointing up towards it. i have now found the control to stop the screen locking in the first place, but that isn't actually the answer.

Comment: All you need to do is press Return, or just start typing your password

Comment: Space key also works, or with a mouse you can press and hold then drag up to dismiss the cover panel.

Answer (score 2):

After the timeout set in Settings > Power > Blank Screen, the screen will switch to a large digital clock and you will need to login again. Start typing your password and the clock will disappear and you'll see the login screen, complete your password and press Return.

Comment: Thank you! Very smart, but not at all logical to anyone who has not come across this feature before.

Comment: @ChrisMathieson I can agree it's not too intuitive, but it's the *de facto* standard for how screensavers work - move the mouse or keyboard input to disable...

Comment: Moving or clicking the mouse brings absolutely no result. Thanks. That was what I tried. Nor has the arrow trick so far, but typing did the trick, followed by clicking on my name and starting the pasword again.

Comment: Escape button works too. This "swipe up" thing is one of the worst design choices ever. Also does not work well with touchpads.